# Should you always pull from the branch that you are on before you push it out using git

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm working with a small team of people. We have a UAT branch that we are all working on. So I made changes to the UAT-Branch last night but did not push out the UAT-Branch with the changes until this morning. I usually do a pull on the branch that I'm working om every morning from just to be safe. I was told this morning that other team members made changes to the UAT-Branch and my push of UAT-Branch doesn't have the new changes because I didn't pull.

I understand that we should pull into the new branch that we are working on but as a team shouldn't there be a cut off in development times. So that developers won't run into this issue?

Or is it just good practice to always pull into the branch that you are working on? This just seems like you're opening yourself to mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it just good practice to always pull into the branch that you are
>   working on ?

Actually I'd say that you should pull the project before committing any changes.

What I like to do is:

```
git stash # Stash your local changes
git pull  # Update code
git stash apply # Merge your local changes
git add
git commit
git push
```

> This just seems like you're opening yourself to mistakes.

I don't see how it open yourself to mistake. I'd argue it is the exact opposite.

Answer (score 1):

In a normal configuration, if you don't pull first (and there are changes to pull) the push would be rejected.  So one of a few things is true:

1) Possibly you used the `-f`, `--force`, or `--force-with-lease` options on your `push` command.  Generally you should not do that unless you have a specific reason and have coordinated with all other repo users.  If abuse of "force pushes" becomes a chronic issue for a team, they can be disabled at the remote.

2) Perhaps your configuration is set up to do forced pushes by default (i.e. the default refspec for your pushes to origin might start with a `+`).  This would have to have been deliberately set up for some reason, so I doubt that's what's happening; but if it is, again, the solution is: don't do that.

3) There may be an observational error, where someone *thinks* they pushed something that your push clobbered, but they're mistaken.

So, to your questions:  Yes, the model for integrating changes is "pull before push", **but** the consequence of not doing so is that your push is rejected and you have to try again the right way.  (If the consequence of such an error were a loss of other developers' changes, then that would happen all the time and git would be useless.)  Which means "try to push, if it fails pull and then push" is a perfectly valid workflow.

And no, there is no need for a cutoff in development times.  The whole point of git is to be usable even with a globally distributed ad hoc team of developers who lack any means of universal coordination.